# CRUD API from article

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to create 4 api calls (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) for the basic node article. I'm a real noob in this. Can someone help me on my way? Where do I go for information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, together with the [REST Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_server) submodule.

The two will allow you to create a new "server" and configure which entities can be retrieved via REST, what the authentication should be and which exactly calls are allowed (get, post, delete, etc.).